# Laravel 5 auth - register redirects to itself

Tags: apache, authentication, laravel-5

My laravel 5 application uses the official auth framework. In my homestead/vagrant environment, all works well but when I try and deploy to the production server, the auth functionality doesn't work - for example, if I try and register a new user, the form redirects to itself and doesn't create the entry in the users table.

Homestead vagrant is running nginx, and the production server is running Apache 2.4.6 (something I don't have control over). mod_rewrite is enabled and the public/.htaccess is as below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I've checked the laravel and apache logs and no errors are logged.

The Apache virtual host configuration is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/app/public"


  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/laravel_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/laravel_access.log" combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE**:
The relevant section of my route list from *php artisan route:list* is:

```
|        | POST      | login                        |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                        |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | logout                       |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web          |
|        | POST      | password/email               |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | password/reset               |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token?}      |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | register                     |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                     |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest    |
```

and the relevant section in the *routes.php* file looks like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::auth();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, managed to solve it - I'll share the answer here.

The site is running https, and I finally realised that the register form was trying to pass the details to an http route which was causing issues.

I modified the auth form to post the form via https and all works.

Comment: That's was some vital information that was missing from your answer. Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the `.htaccess` file to the latest version (below). It could be that a trailing slash in the URL is causing a second redirect.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Niraj, thanks - tried that and didn't solve the problem.